# What does the "J" stand for in Philip J. Fry's name?

Tags: futurama

Is it ever explained what his middle initial stands for?

Comment: You could say that the J is named after Philip J Fry's Grandfather's middle name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*J.* is a middle name initial Groening seems to like to give to his characters. To my knowledge, it is never revealed what name it initials for Fry, but in the case of *Homer J. Simpson* (eponymous character of another Groening show) it is revealed to stand for "Jay" (painted to a wall by his hippie-mother, if I recall correctly). We can only *speculate* that this is also true for Fry.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, the Simpsons case was also a gag (that is, Jay might not neccessarily mean anything important): Homer refers to himself often as Homer J Simpson and it turns out his name is Homer Jay Simpson -- identical when read aloud;; also, Grandpa Simpson is also Abraham J Simpson. :)

Answer (score 1):

The J doesn't stand for anything. Or rather stands for Jay, as in [Jay Ward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay_Ward), creator of The Rocky and Bullwinkle Show.

Comment: If that's true, you should cite a source. Otherwise it just seems like fanciful trivia.

Answer (score -3):

Frys name in futurama is " Philip J. Fry" though it is never clearly stated what the J stands for, in the Simpsons homers name is " Homer Jay Simpson". My guess is that it's the same for Bart, Abe, and Fry.